# Appservice for UWP Onrequestrecieved

Tags: c#, uwp

I am wondering when i create an appservice and create the on requestrecieved event handler is this even handler used if i use a timer trigger as well or is it only used when connected to by an appserviceconnection externally

What i am trying to do is create one app service that is run off a trigger(to update live tiles) and also allow an application to send it information to create targeted live tiles by using an appservice connection.

If this is answered somewhere i have been unable to find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to declare both AppService and BackgroundTask extensions separately in your appxmanifest. If you declare them both to be in-proc they will run in the same process and your scenario can then be seamlessly accomplished.

You should think of it as two different triggers though: one triggers periodically on a timer, and one triggers from an app connecting to the service. Both can trigger the same code/action of course.

Also note that the AppService doesn't need to be running in order for clients to connect to it. The operating system will start it up as needed (and shut it down when no longer needed).